# Krull dimension of this local ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, krull-dimension

I want to know what the Krull dimension of this ring $\mathbb C[x,y]_p/(y^2-x^7,y^5-x^3)$ is, where $p\neq (0,0)$. I know the dimension of it in the origin point, but I don't know other cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $y^2-x^7,y^5-x^3$ are irreducible polynomials (why?) they form a regular sequence in $\mathbb C[x,y]$ and so they are in $\mathbb C[x,y]_{\mathfrak m}$, for any maximal ideal containing them. Then the dimension of $\mathbb C[x,y]_{\mathfrak m}/(y^2-x^7,y^5-x^3)$ is $\dim\mathbb C[x,y]_{\mathfrak m}-2$, that is, $0$.

If $\mathfrak m$ doesn't contain one or both of the polynomials $y^2-x^7,y^5-x^3$, then the quotient ring is $0$.

Comment: I'm ok,I think I should continously study since I don't know regular sequence

Comment: @Chasetheshootingstar: you can also try to show $\mathbb C[x,y]/(y^2-x^7, y^5-x^3)$ has finite dimension as vector space, hence is an Artinian ring. Each localization of an Artinian ring is Artian and has Krull dimension $0$.