# Dimension of local ring as vector space over $\mathbb C$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory

I want to know what the dimension of each of the local ring $\mathbb C[x,y]_p/(y^2-x^7,y^5-x^3)$ is, where $p\neq (0,0)$ over $\mathbb C$-vector space. I know the dimension of it in the origin point, but I don't know other cases.

Comment: Do you know that $\dim_{\mathbb{C}}\mathbb C[x,y]_p/(f,g)$ is the intersection multiplicity of $f,g \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ at $p?$

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know that

Comment: Hint: apply a translation of $\Bbb C^2$ such that $p$ is mapped to the origin.

Comment: See also the previous Q http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561351/

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg,they are the same questions and both from me,I just wonder does the krull dimension equal to the dimension as C-vector space?