# basis of local ring as vector space over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory

Let $m$ be a maximal ideal of quotient ring $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y^2-x^7,y^5-x^3)$. I want to know the dimension and basis of local ring of $R$ by $m$. I understood that $m$ is $(X,Y)$ or $(X-\zeta,Y-\zeta^{18})$, where $\zeta$ is the 29th root of unit. But I can't find the dimension of local ring $R_m$ as vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/563569/dimension-of-local-ring-as-vector-space-over-mathbb-c?rq=1) is the same question.

But I want to know the concrete basis as vector space. It looks impossible for me linear combination of only some basis represent all element $R_m$. Please give me some advice.

Comment: This ring, incidentally, has 30 distinct maximal ideals.

Comment: The question you linked itself links back to [another duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561351/krull-dimension-of-this-local-ring). Did you follow that?

Comment: @Hurkyl: I read that duplicate, but I don't know "Krull dimension" and "regular sequence". Is these knowledge  required for this question?